# Modifying a scraped url and changing its extension

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am new to programming and trying to download images and PDFs from a website.  In the source code, the items I need are in option tags with partial urls.  The site lists these items in a drop-down menu and they display in an iframe, but each item can be opened on its own page using its full url.

So far, my code finds the options, appends the partial url to the page's base address to create the full url for each option, and removes the final " / " from the .tif and .TIF urls and adds a ".pdf".

However, for the .tif and .TIF urls, I need to change "convert" to "pdf" to open them in a new page.  Is there a way to do this to only the .tif.pdf and .TIF.pdf urls while leaving the others unchanged?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import os

my_url = 'http://example.com'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

options = page_soup.findAll("select",{"id":"images"})[0].findAll("option")
values = [o.get("value") for o in options]

split_values = [i.split("|", 1)[0] for i in values]
# The option value is split to separate the url from its label
# <option value="/convert/ASRIMG/new/hop.TIF/|New Form"></option>

new_val = []
for val in split_values:
    ext = os.path.splitext(val.rstrip('/'))[-1]
    new_ext = ext
    if ext.lower() == '.tif':
        new_ext += '.pdf'
    new_val.append(val.rstrip('/').replace(ext, new_ext))

for i in range (len(new_val)):
    image_urls = ('http://example.com' + new_val[i])
```

My current results:

```
print (new_val)

/ASRIMG/good.jpg
/ASRIMG/foo/bar1.jpg
/ASRIMG/foo/bar2.jpg
/ASRIMG/foo/bar3.jpg
/convert/ASRIMG/new/hop.TIF.pdf
/convert/REG/green1.tif.pdf
/convert/REG//green2.tif.pdf
/convert/SHIP/green3.tif.pdf
/convert/SHIP/green4.tif.pdf
/convert/SHIP/green5.tif.pdf
/SKETCHIMG/001.png
/SKETCH/002.JPG


print (image_urls)

http://example.com/ASRIMG/good.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar1.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar2.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar3.jpg
http://example.com/convert/ASRIMG/new/hop.TIF.pdf
http://example.com/convert/REG/green1.tif.pdf
http://example.com/convert/REG//green2.tif.pdf
http://example.com/convert/SHIP/green3.tif.pdf
http://example.com/convert/SHIP/green4.tif.pdf
http://example.com/convert/SHIP/green5.tif.pdf
http://example.com/SKETCHIMG/001.png
http://example.com/SKETCH/002.JPG
```

What I need:

```
http://example.com/ASRIMG/good.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar1.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar2.jpg
http://example.com/ASRIMG/foo/bar3.jpg
http://example.com/pdf/ASRIMG/new/hop.TIF.pdf
http://example.com/pdf/REG/green1.tif.pdf
http://example.com/pdf/REG//green2.tif.pdf
http://example.com/pdf/SHIP/green3.tif.pdf
http://example.com/pdf/SHIP/green4.tif.pdf
http://example.com/pdf/SHIP/green5.tif.pdf
http://example.com/SKETCHIMG/001.png
http://example.com/SKETCH/002.JPG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this step:

```
split_values = [i.split("|", 1)[0] for i in values]
```

This code handles both upper and lower tif:

```
In [48]: import os

In [49]: split_values = ['/ASRIMG/good.jpg', '/convert/ASRIMG/new/hop.TIF/', 'SK
    ...: ETCHIMG/001.png']

In [50]: new_val = []

In [51]: for val in split_values:
    ...:     ext = os.path.splitext(val.rstrip('/'))[-1]
    ...:     new_ext = ext
    ...:     if ext.lower() == '.tif':
    ...:         new_ext += '.pdf'
    ...:     new_val.append(val.rstrip('/').replace(ext, new_ext))
    ...:
    ...:
```

This strips `.tif/` from each value from split_values list from the right side and then adds `.tif.pdf` in the end

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I tried this code out, but it added `.tif.pdf` to all the urls.  In addition to `.tif.pdf` (which is good),  I have : `.jpg.tif.pdf`, `.TIF.tif.pdf`, and `png.tif.pdf`(which gives me an error).

Comment: Edited the code to fix `.TIF/`. What is the expected output for `.jpg.tif` and `.png.tif`?

Comment: The `.jpg`, `.JPG`, and `.png` should not change.  Only `.TIF/` and `.tif/` change to `.TIF.pdf` and `.tif.pdf`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  It took me some time to get the code to run correctly (user error - the code was fine).  The .tif endings are now properly formatted.  Do you have any advice on changing "convert" to "pdf" in the middle of the .tif.pdf and .TIF.pdf urls?

Comment: @shybr Yes, to do that you can do `new_val.append(val.replace('/convert/', '/pdf/', 1).rstrip('/').replace(ext, new_ext))`. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! Thank you again, @Amit Tripathi !